# Need to know why the core file has genereated

Tags: perl, gdb

I have a core file `core.1614762`.

When i do `file core.1614762`, the output is

> core.1614762: ELF 64-bit LSB core file x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), SVR4-style, from '/usr/bin/perl -w /alcatel/omc3/usmcmd/script/cmdsession -f /alcatel/var/home/ax.

What does `/usr/bin/perl -w` indicate above?

I did gdb of the core file (`gdb /usr/bin/perl core.1614762`); the backtrace is showing `Perl_csighandler`.

```
#0  0x000000384ca95002 in Perl_csighandler () from /usr/lib64/perl5/CORE/libperl.so
#1  <signal handler called>
#2  0x000000384a235e30 in __cxa_finalize () from /lib64/libc.so.6`enter code here`
#3  0x0000003855e1bdd6 in ?? () from /usr/lib64/firefox/libnspr4.so
#4  0x0000000000000017 in ?? ()
#5  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

I don't know why the core file was generated . Can I find out why the core file was generated from the above info?

Answer (score 1):

> *what does "/usr/bin/perl -w " indicate above?*

The program that was being executed (`perl`) and its first argument (`-w`, which enabled warnings).

> *Can i find why thecore file has generated from the above info.*

Looks like the exception happened in the signal handler. I wouldn't be surprised if this happened because the programmer explicitly disabled [safe signals](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Deferred-Signals-(Safe-Signals)) or installed his own handler using `POSIX::sigaction`. This is an expected consequence.

Comment: Hi ikegami,        There is no POSIX::sigaction in the code.The code has  'use POSIX ":sys_wait_h"  ' line. Does it create any exception in the signal handler.                        please suggest

Comment: Nah, that just imports symbols including `WNOHANG`

Comment: The above stack is not sufficient to analyse the problem. Is there  any way to get more stack from gdb?

Comment: Recompiling your Perl with symbols (or switching to a locally-installed Perl compiled with symbols) will show more. Easy to do, and I'll give you instructions if you want. You'll need to get another core file afterwards, though

Comment: Hi ikegami, Thanks for answering to my question :) :) . Please give instructions for more stack. please suggest some solution to this core file. You told about exception happened in the signal handler. is there any way to resolve  this expection?

Comment: If it's due to unsafe signals, don't rien on unsafe signals. If it's due to `sigaction` being used,  don't use it.  Should happen otherwise. /// Instructions to come later today